# How to get the username from the window authentication in Angular?

Tags: angular, authentication, web, angular9

Recently I have implemented the Angular project and have implemented the window authentication in Web Api. For example:

```
<security>
<authorization>
<remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
<add accessType="Allow" roles="the group that i allow to add " />
</authorization>
</security>
```

So once I ng serve and run the angular project to open the website it will prompt out the window authentication like this.

[Pop out window authentication image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxGU7.png)

But how can I retrieve the username have entered the window authentication after successful login into the angular website? As I need to get a username for some purpose after login into the angular.

Comment: I don’t think you can directly... but maybe if the server knows it somehow? Then you would need an API to fetch it..

Comment: Hmmm api? You mean create a service in angular and call from the API and get the username something like this? `var userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity?.Name; `

Comment: You’d call an API from the angular app.. so you ask the server I guess..?

Comment: yaya, ask from our own server.

Comment: Right. I’m afraid that is your only option.. I do not think your clientside code has access to that context in any way..

Comment: I see, then do you know the code that I can use in web api to fetch the username after the service have call the controller in the web api?

Comment: Not sure how you would handle that serverside really..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try a way by posting a window event(Window.postMessage), that can be easily catched in your angular app, this way you can achieve this